# How to solve the optimization problem whose optimization variable is a function?

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, calculus-of-variations

My opimization problem is related to finding an optimal probability density function (pdf) $f(t)$ to minimize the following objective.

> Find $\min\limits_{f(t)} C$ such that:$$1+\frac{b\cdot\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt}{x}\leq C, \text{ for any }x\in(0,\infty)$$
> $$\frac{\int_{0}^{x}(t+b)\cdot f(t)dt+x\cdot\int_{x}^{\infty}f(t)dt}{b}\leq C, \text{ for any }x\in(b,\infty)$$
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)dt=1$$
> Here $b$ is a known constant.

I want to find the optimal pdf to minimize $C$, but do not know how to solve it.

Are there any systematic ways or general ideas of dealing with such a functional optimization problem?

Comment: I guess some context would be needed here. Where does that problem come from? At first sight, this will be difficult to solve analytically, not because of the fact that the decision variable is a function but because you have an infinite number of constraints.

Comment: A classical method when minimizing functionals is the [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations). Typically, in these settings, the exact space of functions you're working with and its topology are both important.

Comment: @KBS I think there is only 1 constraint ($\int f = 1$). The other inequalities are just a definition of the objective $C[f]$ which is somehow a kind of maximum of two supremum over $x$ of some quantities depending on $f$.

Comment: @erik I think this is a very nice question. If you get no answer here after a few days or a week, you could post the same on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) which is for research-level questions. You could maybe rather define $C$ as a max of sup to make things clearer.

Comment: @cs89 No, the two inequality constraints are constraints of the optimization problem and both of them need to be satisfied for all $x$ in some interval. This means that we have as many constraints as there are $x$'s.

Comment: The reason why I have this optimization problem is that I am trying to solve a cost optimization problem for a distributed storage system, constant $b$ here is the cost of transferring the data object among different servers. $f(t)$ here is the pdf of the storage duration of the data copy in a server (and storage cost is proportional to the storage duration, here we assume that the storage cost rate is 1 per unit of time), and after time $t$ the data will be dropped in the server so that there will be no storage cost anymore for our server.

Comment: @KBS So our algorithm is something like a randomized online algorithm, whose target is to find the optimal pdf $f(t)$ to minimized the overall cost of storing and transferring data in the system. Through some simplifications of my modelling, I finally derive this functional optimization problem, but do not know what to do next.

Comment: @cs89  This problem has infinitely many constraints (i.e., for each continuous value $x\in (0,\infty)$, we have constraints like the first and the second constraint), and this is the mainly obstacle of solving this optimization problem.